# How do I define a static boost shared pointer?

Tags: c++, boost, static, initialization, shared-ptr

How do I define `cloud` outside the class?

```
typedef pcl::PointCloud<pclPoint> pclPointCloud
class Deformer{
    public:
    static pclPointCloud::Ptr cloud;
};
pclPointCloud::Ptr Deformer::cloud = ??;    // What to write here
```

Can't I define it using NULL, or something like `pclPointCloud::Ptr Deformer::cloud = boost::shared_ptr<pclPointCloud>(NULL);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be default constructed if you simply remove the `= ??` part.  This is the same as setting it to null (i.e. calling `reset()`).

By the way, something interesting about class statics is that even POD types like raw pointers and integral types will by default have the value zero when your program starts.  So even an "uninitialized" raw pointer will be null.

Comment: I had to wait for 8 minutes